# Provide single sign on information from lightsaml to Gigya

Tags: php, symfony, saml, gigya

I am using [lightsaml](https://www.lightsaml.com) (LightSAML is a stack of PHP libraries and bundles implementing OASIS' SAML 2.0 protocol).

I would like to make lightsaml work with Gigya.

How do I generate the following information using lightsaml in order to setup them into Gigya SAML IdP (Identity Provider) settings:

- Single-Sign-On Service URL
- Single-Sign-On Service Binding
- Single Logout Service URL
- Single Logout Service Binding
- Name ID Format

Comment: Reformat list of desired settings.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gigya SAML IdP, you can get the information needed by the SP by clicking on the **SAML IdP Metadata** link of the SAML Identity Provider dashboard.

https://console.gigya.com/site/partners/Settings.aspx#cmd%3DSAML.SamlIdpApp

You can see the documentation [here](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Gigya+as+SAML+IdP#GigyaasSAMLIdP-IdPSetup).

If, however, what you are referring to is using lightsaml **as** the SAML IdP within Gigya, that is not supported. You could configure a Gigya Idp, then build your own layer on top of that which supports lightsaml and relays all the calls between the two, but it would be a lot of additional work with no real benefit.